# How to determine the type of a object of a reference class

Tags: r, reference-class

I have list of objects of different types of reference classes. How to determine the type of the folowing class? Should I use the function `class`?

```
A<-setRefClass(Class = "A", fields = c(var1 = "ANY"))
a<-A(var1=1)
class(a)=="A"
b<-list(A(var1=1),A(var1=1))
lapply(b, function(x) class(x)=="A")
```

Comment: probably you want `is(a, "A")` to include possibility of inheritance, e.g., `is(a, "refClass")`.